# New tag? [phial-of-galadriel]

Tags: discussion, tags

I am to ask a question which concerns the Phial.  Does anyone see need to make a new tag, or should I be content with the two other tags on my question?
(Those tags are [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) and [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) — probably specific enough.)

Comment: You don't really need to ask for the creation of the tag, but I'd say No. No one can really be an "expert" in the Phial of Galadriel, and it's unlikely anyone would search specifically for questions about the phial.

Comment: I feel like we once had and subsequently deleted this.

Comment: I kinda thought so too; one of the reasons I wanted to ask first.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted so heavily. It's not a proposal to create a new tag, but a neutral question about *whether or not* one is needed.

Answer (score 4):

As first proffered by [Edlothiad](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68872):

## No.

No one can really be an "expert" in the Phial of Galadriel, and it's unlikely anyone would search specifically for questions about the phial.

Comment: I don't think it's unlikely. It's just that if you search phial and Lord of the Rings, or Galadriel, you're not going to get many results, let alone false positives. It's a term that's very easy to find without needing a tag.

Comment: This doesn't need to be community wiki. You can revert it to your own answer. @CreationEdge, It is very unlikely one can be SOLELY an expert in the Phial of Galadriel, it's far too minor of an object. It'd be like having a tag for hobbit-feet (no if you suggest it I'll end you forever)

Comment: @Edlothiad I'm not saying we need a tag just providing a different explanation of for why we *don't* need it.

Comment: @Edlothiad - please don't tempt me :)

Comment: CreationEdge makes a sage point, and could probably proffer that as an answer itself.  Me, I'd disagree with this — I would now consider myself a modicate novice in the Phial; I also do not quite understand what was meant with the “solely an expert” remark — you mean knowledge of the Phial is only gained by studying other things in the mythos?  I think I can see the reasons for seeing it in such a frame.

Comment: As for [tag:hobbit-feet] — surely you are aware they are not a “minor” object to some people, eh?  (If not — hehe; throw out a few web searches.)